# Create and distribute .Jar files for android in Eclipse

Tags: android, jar, shared-libraries, executable-jar

In android I need to create a library file`(.Jar file)` to distribute it to third party people to integrate that functionality within their android apps.

Bit struggling of deciding what the best approach. Yes I can create an android library project and implement the functionality seperately and test it with my main project, but wonder how to create a `.Jar` file out of that (I know it works perfect with the `.Jar` file that automatically creates under the bin filder in library project but don't think its the best practice as it automatically creates and we dont have any control over it).

I serched this thing but didn't get an exact way to do this. But I am pretty much sure its possible as we already have `.Jar files` available to integrate with android.

If someone can explain the steps that I have to follow to create a `.Jar` file for android it would be great. I am using `Eclipse` as the IDE.

In my case I am `NOT` using any resourses from the library project and just few classes that have public methods in it to call from the main project.

Thanks.

Comment: you cannot package resource files into jar. you can package pure java class files into jar files

Comment: I am not using any resource files. just few classes from library project. Thanks.